# Processing time for Romania visa applications

Tags: visas, romania

I applied for a Romania visa on Sunday. I'm currently waiting for my application to be processed. Do you know how long it takes for the Romanian consulate in Washington DC to process a visa application? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [Romanian Embassy page](https://washington.mae.ro/en/node/427) says:

> Upon receiving, the documents are legally processed in up to 14 days
>   (C-type visas) and up to 30 days (D-type visas).

You'll find the full process outlined there - processing times are given under Step 6.

Note that it also says

> **The online application does NOT process the visa request! It only verifies that the legal requirements are met.**

Have you submitted your documents yet? If not, the processing time listed above hasn't yet started.